# Parse.com: can orderDescending deal with more than 1M row of data? is it Scalable?

Tags: ios, data-structures, parse-platform

I am doing Objective C IOS coding.
Parse.com: can orderDescending deal with more than 1M row of data? is it Scalable?

I am using parse to store score of a lot of items/users and I am planning to use OrderDescending method to return the top 100 items/users.

Can OrderDescending deal with more than 1M items and is it scalable? Is there any limitation at all? If it's scalable it will be very easy for me to deal with the top 100 items problem.

Or should I do this work in another way? For example, Maybe I can create another table called Top100 table which hold no more than 100 items. Everytime a user has a new high score I will look into this table and see if I should insert this user and his high score into this table. If so, I will insert it and remove the last item.

How did you guys deal with this kind of problem? (listing top 100 players or items among more than 500K to a few million rows of items)

Answer (score 0):

There are limits on the amount of time your request will run for before it times out, depending on the data type you're using for sorting you could well hit that limit. Larger data sets definitely take longer to process.

The additional table is a sensible approach to take, it makes the management easy, the lookup fast and removes concern about +Xmillion users.